# Backspace while entering filename in JFileChooser makes directory go one level back

Tags: windows, swing, jfilechooser

I am pretty new to Java Swing development and is encountering the following issue and not certain how to resolve it.

While providing a file name  to save a file using JFileChooser, entering a backspace(in the filename field), makes a directory go up 1 level. This problem is encountered only on  Windows and not on Linux.

Can somebody shed some light on why this may happening and an approach to fix this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem too. 
My solution - is to override the processKeyBinding method , and in the specific case stop the method , see below:

```
 @Override 
  protected boolean processKeyBinding(KeyStroke ks, KeyEvent e,
                                        int condition, boolean pressed) {

        if (KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE ==  e.getKeyChar()){
            if (jTextField!= null && jTextField.hasFocus()) 
                return false; 
        }

        return super.processKeyBinding (ks,e,condition,pressed);     
    }
```

the jTextField is the filename field that , was calculated in the contractor of **my** FileChooser class

the method to calculate is -

```
private Component getTextFieldInJFileChooser(Component [] c )
    {
        if (c == null)
            return null;

        for(Component k: c)
        {
             if( k instanceof JTextField) {
                return k;
             }
             else if(k instanceof JPanel) {
                 JPanel jp=(JPanel)k;
                 Component jTextField = getTextFieldInJFileChooser(jp.getComponents());
                 if (jTextField != null)
                     return jTextField;
             }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Success & Regards!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This seemed to have happened due to a config in our application. I changed that and got it to work.